# How to get coordinates of a pixel if I have its RGB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

So, I want to check if there's a pixel in a certain area of my screen with the RGB "0,158,187", if so, I want to get its coordinates so that I can click there.

Here's what I tried:

```
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(268,118,1150,866))
x = 268
y = 118
while True:
    x = x + 5
    xy = (x, y)
    if im.getpixel(xy) == (0,158,187):
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        break
    if x >= 1150:
        x = 268
        y = y + 5
    if y >= 866:
        sys.exit()
```

However, I keep getting an error

```
 "IndexError: image index out of range"
```

even though I constantly reset the X range when it reaches 1150 & end the program if Y reaches 866 since theres no point continuing them.

Comment: `268` incremented by `5` is going to end up with a larger value then `1150`. Then before your condition checking that, it will attempt to `im.getpixel(xy)` at coordinates that do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing x before calling getpixel, so when it x become greater or equal than 1150, you first call getpixel, then test x to reset the range.

I think this is more appropriate to do :

```py
while True:
    xy = (x, y)
    if im.getpixel(xy) == (0,158,187):
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        break
    x = x + 5
    if x >= 1150:
        x = 268
        y = y + 5
    if y >= 866:
        sys.exit()
```